# how to make the Textbox to allow only three digits with three decimal points?

Tags: jquery, regex, user-input

I want to make the textbox allow only **three digits and three decimals.For example 999.999**.similarly it doesnt allow any characters like a,b,/,etc.**How can I do with the Jquery?**

Comment: I accept the answer.Please visit my profile.I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Replaced tag 'php' with 'regex' as this question has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the jQuery.validate plugin?

```
$('#formid').validate({
    rules: {
        fieldname: {
            required:function(element) {
                return /^\s*[0-9]{,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?\s*$/.test(element.value);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: admittedly I didn't test the regex and merely wanted to demonstrate how it works.
Updated regex as per nickf's suggestion, thanks.

Comment: this doesn't even work. any value with any numbers or a dot will pass the validation: `"1234.5678", "hello."`, etc

Comment: suggested change: `/^\s*[0-9]{,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?\s*$/`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQuery numeric plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/).

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at this [masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin